# Hide and Display elements using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have a header for the page with  horizontal  menu navigation like A B C. A has sub menus D, E and B has sub-menus F and G. By default on the header F and G are hidden.now when I click on B , F and G should be visible while D and E should be hidden. I created a small function which sets the display property of the sub-menus when their respective menus are clicked, this works but as the page loads I am back to square one, which means D and E are shown and F and G are hidden.

How can solve this using JavaScript? I am very new to js so not thinking in terms of jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if possible you could add a hash `#` to the new URL. Look for that and base which to show via JavaScript.

Pseudo code: **[Example Here](http://jsbin.com/udaje/4)**  --  **[Source to example here](http://jsbin.com/udaje/4/edit)**

```
var hash = location.hash
if(hash == '#menuA' || hash == '') {
    //show menuA
} else if( hash == '#menuB' ) {
   // show B
.....etc
```

Answer (score 1):

You could set a cookie with information on which menu is selected, and then read the cookie and set the menu appropriately when a page is loaded. You can find some nice cookie cutter functions here: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I only know jQuery well enough to accomplish what I think you want offhand.
Maybe the pseudo-code will help.  It might help if you post the html you used to make the sub-menus.

This sample simply associates a nav element with an object on the page.

SCRIPT (preferably in an external .js file linked to by all pages):

```
//after you've set all sub-menus to display:none

//for each nav element
$('#nav a').each(function(){  //just like a for loop
    var a,b;
    // set a equal to the contents of the current nav element in the loop
    a =$(this).html();
    //set b equal to the contents of the first <h2> element on the current page
    //or to whatever you want to use to distinguish as "a match" (needs not be visible)
    b =$('h2:first').html();  
    //if the match is made... in this case, an exact match
    if(a == b){
            //Here you would have your display children code
            //or display D and E or F and G code, depending on how you've set it up               
        }else //code to execute if no match is made
    });
```

I had to figure this out for a team project... I've got a lot to learn too.  Love it

Answer (score 0):

This is quite simple via jQuery, actually. I mocked up a very basic menu with unordered lists and list items [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jwiscarson/362Mx/).

I know you mentioned that you are very new to JavaScript, and I certainly understand, but familiarizing yourself with frameworks like jQuery is absolutely essential. The selector functionality in jQuery is extremely powerful.

Comment: Thanks for the help.I would surely start familiarizing myself jquery.